# How to set the textsize, textcolor and other parameters for the imagebutton in android?

Tags: android, xml, user-interface, imagebutton

How to set the text size, text color and other parameters in one xml and than assign them to the imagebutton in android? 
I can set the parameters manually for each button, but if there are more than 3 buttons it becomes a nightmare. What is the best practices for doing this?

Comment: Learn some basic of Android development for reusable resources, you can create the styles in /res/values/ and use these style in similar looking widgets, by style="@style/your_style"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use styles for that
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Answer (score 1):

Create a `style` depending on your requirement's add that to your button like this `style="@style/your_style"`.  look at this tutorial [Styles and Themes](http://www.vogella.com/articles/AndroidStylesThemes/article.html)

Answer (score 0):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<resources>
    <style name="CustomText" parent="@style/Text">
        <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">#008</item>
    </style>
</resources>

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<EditText
    style="@style/CustomText"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Hello, World!" />


<TextView
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:textColor="#00FF00"
    android:typeface="monospace"
    android:text="@string/hello" />
```

Comment: The warning: Unexpected text found in layout file: "20sp". I don't know if it matters but i put the style xml in drawable folder